# How many ports does a mobile OS have?

Tags: android, ios, networking

I was just wondering if the number of ports on the Android or iOS is limited as compared to a PC. I was investigating into a network issue in one of my apps and this is a question that came to my mind, whether the number or ports on a mobile device is small and if that causes blocking of requests until they they become free

Comment: TCP requires that a port number be in the range 1-65535. I guess that an implementation is free not to allow them all at once. I don't see any reason why a mobile device would do so however. They have plenty of memory.

Comment: Okay I get your point. I got hold of someone who has written the Android OS and he told me that it would behave just like any Linux system would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, ports numbers are related to TCP packets and it's ranging shouldn't be related to the iOS or Android OS structure.

Each TCP packet includes source port and destination port fields, both being 16-bit long (65536 numbers). The field is there every time and with the same length and because it is generally accepted structure, it wouldn't make sense to limit it.

PS: In your implementation don't forget to keep in mind [Well-known and Registered ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_port). If you use a port number that is being used by another application, weird things may (and will) happen.